# booting after emergency mode in debian

Tags: debian, boot, kernel-modules

My laptop stopped booting after (I think) an update. I'm saying think, because booting with the previous kernel version does not work either.

I'm running Debian with kernel 5.10.0-10-amd64. After `loading initial ramdisk` I get the message

```
NVRM: no NVIDIA GPU found.
```

three times. I have no NVIDIA GPU so not sure why that message is there. It follows with

```
[FAILED] Failed to start: Load Kernel Modules
iwlwifi: firmware: failed to load
```

and that it's one I do need.

At the end it says

```
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Cannot open access to console, the tot account is locked. See sulogin(8) man page for more details.
Press Enter to continue.
```

By pressing enter, I only get to this same state. Other than going into the grub menu, there does not seem to be anything else to do.

Is there a way out of this other than a rescue disc?

Comment: are you using a bootloader, such as GRUB?

Comment: Yes, as I said, the only place I can do something is the grub menu: editing the entries (nvidia.modeset) and using the mini command shell. But I don't know if I can do anything useful there.